# Mistake in MySQL query / sports table + schedule

Tags: mysql, sql

My intention is to create standings from my schedule that contains results from the last 3 matchdays. I have two tables, one contains information about my sport teams, the other one contains the schedule.

Now I'm seeking for a way to put the match results into the standings. Until now everything works fine, except that my query doesn't count the 3rd matchday correctly. The 3rd matchday was a 1:1 draw in every match.

Standings:

```
Team#1  3 Matches, 2 Wins, 0 Draws, 0 Losses
Team#2  3 Matches, 2 Wins, 0 Draws, 0 Losses
```

etc.

MySQL table "teams":

[image: MySQL table "teams"]

MySQL table "competition_schedule":

[image: MySQL table "competition_schedule"]

The query:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   name, 
   logo, 
   SUM(matches) AS `matches`,
   SUM(w) AS `win`,
   SUM(d) AS `draw`,
   SUM(l) AS `loss`,
   SUM(goals) AS `goals`, 
   SUM(goals_against) AS `goals_against`, 
   (SUM(goals)-SUM(goals_against)) AS `dif`, 
   SUM(pts) AS `pts`
FROM(
   SELECT
     t.`id`, 
     t.`name`,
     t.`logo`,
     COUNT(cs.`public`) AS `matches`,
     SUM(cs.`home-team_score`) AS `goals`,
     SUM(cs.`guest-team_score`) AS `goals_against`,
     IF( cs.`home-team_score` > cs.`guest-team_score`, 3, 
         IF( cs.`home-team_score` = cs.`guest-team_score`, 1, 0 )
     ) AS `pts`,
     IF( cs.`home-team_score` > cs.`guest-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `w`,
     IF( cs.`home-team_score` = cs.`guest-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `d`,
     IF( cs.`home-team_score` < cs.`guest-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `l`
   FROM
     team t
   LEFT JOIN
     competition_schedule cs
   ON
     (
       t.`id` = cs.`home-team_id`
     )
   WHERE cs.`public`         = 1
   AND   cs.`season`         = 1
   AND   cs.`matchday`      <= 12
   AND    cs.`association_id` = 1
   GROUP BY t.`id`

UNION ALL

   SELECT
     t.`id`, 
     t.`name`, 
     t.`logo`,
     COUNT(cs.`public`) AS `matches`,
     SUM(cs.`guest-team_score`) AS `goals`,
     SUM(cs.`home-team_score`) AS `goals_against`,
     IF( cs.`guest-team_score` > cs.`home-team_score`, 3, 
       IF( cs.`guest-team_score` = cs.`home-team_score`, 1, 0 )
     ) AS `pts`,
     IF( cs.`guest-team_score` > cs.`home-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `w`,
     IF( cs.`guest-team_score` = cs.`home-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `d`,
     IF( cs.`guest-team_score` < cs.`home-team_score`, 1, 0) AS `l`
   FROM
     team t
   LEFT JOIN
     competition_schedule cs
   ON
     (
       t.`id` = cs.`guest-team_id`
     )
   WHERE cs.`public`         = 1
   AND   cs.`season`         = 1
   AND   cs.`matchday`      <= 12
   AND    cs.`association_id` = 1
   GROUP BY t.`id`    
 ) alle
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY pts DESC, dif DESC, goals DESC
```

Comment: testing it over and over but nothing helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5b049/2/0

Comment: solved it by simplifing the whole query... for those who are interested, check also: http://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/sql/league-table-in-mysql and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5b049/35 (my solution)